# Require more of/from inanimate objects

Tags: british-english

Can you

> require more of your equipment

or

> require more from your equipment

in the sense of asking more of it, i.e. demand equipment that performs better/is able to fulfill a greater amount of functions and in a more satisfactory manner?

What about 'demand more of/demand more from'?

I am following British English usage.

For a bit of context: 'If your job requires more of you, you should require more of your equipment.'

It's possible that if 'from' is used in the second part of the construction, it ought also be used in the first part.

At the moment, everything is starting to look in turns equally preposterous and equally acceptable to me.

The 'of' construction contains, perhaps, a greater level of ambiguity even if acceptable.

Comment: 'Require more of your equipment' is unusual in either sense. 'Need / expect your equipment to work better', 'expect more from your equipment' etc would be far more colloquial in that sense, while if you needed more equipment with your name on it  than was readily available, context would inform that usage. You're right when you say that your first predicate is ambiguous, but if we worried too much about every potential ambiguity, English would have died out as a language. And the English etc as a people.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "require more of your equipment" is that it potentially misleads the reader into thinking that you are asking for more equipment, not, as is the case, for more out of your equipment.

On grounds of clarity alone, 'from' should be used in the second part of the sentence.

It is purely a matter of style whether to read that construction back into the first part. Personally, I wouldn't.

Comment: There's a hint to a compromise answer in this answer: add "out". As @JeremyC writes himself, you could use "more *out* of your equipment", thus keeping the *of* and maintaining the symmetry of your whole sentence (advert?)

Comment: "On grounds of clarity alone, 'from' should be used in the second part of the sentence." Only if context doesn't suffice to clearly disambiguate (and yes, _prior_ context, to preclude the misleading you mention).